# Can I use Google Play gift cards in my country?

Tags: google-play-store

I recently found out that there are now Google Play gift cards. Something I've been looking forward to. The downer? It's not available for sale at my country (Philippines). So I want to know, if I get a friend from the US buy a card for me and send me the card code, will I be able to use it on my account that is based in the Philippines? I'm asking this because when I tried going to the [redeem page](https://play.google.com/redeem?hl=en), it said it's unavailable for my country and thus, didn't provide me with any way to enter a redeem code.

What I have in mind is I would TeamView my friend's PC on the US and log-in my account there then I will top-up my Google Play account that way. The question is, will it work? I mean, won't it detect that I was logging in from the Philippines just awhile ago? I wouldn't want to waste money with buying a gift card if it won't be usable anyway. My friend is an iOS user so I can't just sell it to him either.

Comment: It will work. I regularly access my Google account from different countries (via VPN) and it doesn't complain since I'M using the same computer. You might try http://tunnelbear.com instead of TeamView. But it should work either way.

Comment: What do I do when it asks for my address and other location info?

Comment: It does that? Just Google "pizza new york" and pick a nice place :) That's what I do usually.

Comment: Is one of you two willing to compile the comments into an answer? Or would you object if I do? I hate questions without (or with "hidden") answers :)

Answer (score 2):

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3422734?hl=en

> Can only be used to purchase or rent content sold in local currency.
>
> If you purchase a Google Play gift card or redeem a promotional code in Australia and then travel to Germany, you won’t be able to redeem your Google Play balance since paid content is sold in Euros.